# ActivityMapper with Gin and AsyncProvider

Tags: gwt, gwt-gin

I've just started a project built with the [new GWT archetype](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes/tree/master/guice-rf-activitie).

ActivityMapper looks like:

```
public interface Factory {
    HomeActivity homeActivity();

    GreetingActivity greetingActivity(String user);
}

private final Factory factory;

@Inject
MainActivityMapper(Factory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
}

@Override
public Activity getActivity(Place place) {
    if (place instanceof HomePlace) {
        return factory.homeActivity();
    }
    if (place instanceof GreetingPlace) {
        GreetingPlace greetingPlace = (GreetingPlace) place;
        return factory.greetingActivity(greetingPlace.getUser());
    }
    logger.severe("Unhandled place type: " + place.getClass().getName());
    return null;
}
```

I'm now trying to implement code split with AsyncProvider based on [this example](http://ars-codia.raphaelbauer.com/2011/04/gwt-gin-and-simple-split-points.html), but I can't get it working.

When using ActivityAsyncProxy, what should I do? return the ActivityAsyncProxy from getActivity(Place place)? but then, how can I create the ActivityAsyncProxy from the factory?

How would you suggest to make the activity mapper play nicely with code split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICT, you cannot use `AsyncProvider` with assisted inject (that would be a great addition to GIN). That means you cannot benefit from generated `runAsync` calls, you'd have to do them yourself.

Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5129 for discussion of this issue, with several proposals.

Also have a look at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit-contributors/bUFYWEFskBI/ja2aJ0tBgdwJ for my own take on it (also available at https://gist.github.com/3038878).

Comment: Thanks for the code samples Thomas, can you please clarify on what should I implement in 
void doAsync(RunAsyncCallback callback);
and
Activity createInstance();

Its a bit confusing, can I use GIN to implement createInstance(), and AsyncProvider for the doAsync()?

Comment: I just added a comment to the Gist with an example of use.